# Can a Jekyll site be a sub site within an existing website?

Tags: jekyll

I'm managing a site that is generated by Jekyll and hosted on github. The product manager does not like the home page and wants to redesign it and has asked if it could be created separately from the rest of the site (which is Jekyll).

Personally I'd love to pull the whole site out of Jekyll as what we are doing and what Jekyll is made for are two different things. But budget and time are factors and doing a major overhaul is not in the foreseeable future.

Has anyone tried this and if so what are the pain points/best practices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck. That is not a complex task AT ALL. Just create a folder called _layouts in the root and create a 'customhome.html' file in it.

Then create an 'index.md' file in the root and set this:

```
---
title: Home
layout: customhome
---
```

Write your whole (custom) webpage in the 'customhome.html' file, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

As a bonus you can test your customhome.html file directly in your browser without intalling Jekyll (as long as you keep everyting inline).

PS. You can even forget the above and put a simple 'index.html' file in the root... that works too! Make sure you delete the existing 'index.md' file if available.